# How to implement save before leaving using nz-tabset?

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

I am using zorro antd to implement multiple tabs feature, I would like to warn my user when they have unsaved changes, and only leave the tab if the user confirms. Seems there isn't a callback before leaving the tab, (nzSelectChange) is the call back after tab changed instead of before. So how can I implement a feature like this using nz-tabset of zorro?

Answer (score 0):

NzTab has a `(nzClick)` EventEmitter to handler the tab title click event, but it does not emit the native mouse-event, so we cannot capture the native event. But I found the nz-tab `[nzTitle]` property can be a `TemplateRef`, so we can build our tab title and handler the click event before triggering tab-set's `(nzSelectChange)`. For Example:

```
<ng-template #tabTitle1>
   <div (click)="beforeActivateTab(0, $event)">Tab 1</div>
</ng-template>
```

And, I build an online example you can visit here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-drc5uf